# Where can I find Hadoop logs in cloudera cdh 5.10 and How to load these (Hadoop node logs) into HDFS using Flume

Tags: hadoop, flume, cloudera-cdh, flume-ng

Till now all I could manage to find is this, that inside /var/log/hadoop-yarn directory I could see following .out and .log files.
But I am not sure whether these are actually called the hadoop log files that I need to load into hdfs. If these are the files we mean when we say hadoop log files  then what kind of my .conf file would look like to be able to load these into hdfs successfully.

```
[cloudera@quickstart /]$ cd /var/log/hadoop-yarn
[cloudera@quickstart hadoop-yarn]$ ls -lart
total 2684
-rw-r--r--   1 yarn yarn       704 Nov  3 12:40 yarn-yarn-nodemanager-quickstart.cloudera.out.2
-rw-r--r--   1 yarn yarn       704 Nov  3 12:40 yarn-yarn-proxyserver-quickstart.cloudera.out.2
-rw-r--r--   1 yarn yarn       704 Nov  3 12:40 yarn-yarn-resourcemanager-quickstart.cloudera.out.2
-rw-r--r--   1 yarn yarn       704 Nov  4 01:40 yarn-yarn-nodemanager-quickstart.cloudera.out.1
-rw-r--r--   1 yarn yarn       704 Nov  4 01:40 yarn-yarn-proxyserver-quickstart.cloudera.out.1
-rw-r--r--   1 yarn yarn       704 Nov  4 01:40 yarn-yarn-resourcemanager-quickstart.cloudera.out.1
-rw-r--r--   1 yarn yarn       704 Nov  4 01:50 yarn-yarn-nodemanager-quickstart.cloudera.out
-rw-r--r--   1 yarn yarn       704 Nov  4 01:50 yarn-yarn-proxyserver-quickstart.cloudera.out
-rw-r--r--   1 yarn yarn     72615 Nov  4 01:50 yarn-yarn-proxyserver-quickstart.cloudera.log
-rw-r--r--   1 yarn yarn       704 Nov  4 01:50 yarn-yarn-resourcemanager-quickstart.cloudera.out
drwxr-xr-x   2 yarn yarn      4096 Nov  4 01:52 containers
-rw-r--r--   1 yarn yarn    116956 Nov  4 01:54 yarn-yarn-resourcemanager-quickstart.cloudera.log
-rw-r--r--   1 yarn yarn    105950 Nov  4 01:54 yarn-yarn-nodemanager-quickstart.cloudera.log
drwxr-xr-x   2 yarn hadoop    4096 Nov  4 10:28 stacks
drwxrwxr-x   5 yarn hadoop    4096 Nov  4 10:28 .
drwxr-xr-x. 41 root root      4096 Dec  4 08:46 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 yarn yarn   1710159 Dec  4 10:14 hadoop-cmf-yarn-NODEMANAGER-quickstart.cloudera.log.out
drwxr-xr-x   2 yarn hadoop    4096 Dec  4 10:46 container
-rw-r--r--   1 yarn yarn    671383 Dec  4 10:46 hadoop-cmf-yarn-RESOURCEMANAGER-quickstart.cloudera.log.out
[cloudera@quickstart hadoop-yarn]$
```

Comment: Hadoop has lots of log files. These are the YARN process logs... Unclear if you wanted the datanode logs, or the namenode logs, or the mapreduce app logs.....

Comment: Please show your current attempts at a Flume conf file

Comment: to be exact I wanted to load namenode logs into hdfs using flume.

Comment: Namenode isn't part of YARN. Try looking under  `/var/log/hadoop/`

Comment: there is no directory within /var/log that says only hadoop [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ cd /var/log/hadoop
bash: cd: /var/log/hadoop: No such file or directory
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ cd /var/log
[cloudera@quickstart log], I tried listing inside log directory, I could not see any directory with name hadoop only, though I can see hadoop-hdfs, hadoop-yarn and hadoop-mapreduce.

Comment: Sorry, the namenode is part of `hadoop-hdfs`